# How to fix H20 error when deploying app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, nuxt.js, heroku-cli

My app works fine locally and I have deployed before in the past with success, for some reason it is no longer working.

The build is successful but when I access the app it states there is an error and directs me to the error log.

UPDATE: The app has come online by itself and working. Just today I did another deploy and same thing with the logs.

I've got an updated log report which may help with identifying the issue below:

```
2019-01-10T18:09:25.137016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=extremeparts.happyfeed.io request_id=416dd308-07ef-431d-9f84-d11dd0ebb2a2 fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-01-10T18:09:32.777385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=extremeparts.happyfeed.io request_id=397e7c62-3274-4cdf-b26e-f00f2c99ee21 fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-01-10T18:09:33.881452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=extremeparts.happyfeed.io request_id=61e77c1f-1edb-4c68-becb-595a4aa5bcca fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-01-10T18:10:41.103152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=extremeparts.herokuapp.com request_id=ff3479ff-5b56-46a3-8714-66e6d9641569 fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-10T18:10:46.334074+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=extremeparts.herokuapp.com request_id=2633d447-0f58-4f5d-951f-2f01360b7eb1 fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-10T18:13:29.357357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-10T18:13:37.398825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-01-10T18:13:40.904693+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-10T18:13:40.904720+00:00 app[web.1]: > sms-funnel@1.0.0 start /app
2019-01-10T18:13:40.904722+00:00 app[web.1]: > nuxt build && nuxt start
2019-01-10T18:13:40.904723+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-10T18:13:42.545513+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-10T18:13:42.545554+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN  vendor has been deprecated due to webpack4 optimization        18:13:42
2019-01-10T18:13:42.545556+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-10T18:13:46.442346+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ Compiling Client                                         webpackbar 18:13:46
2019-01-10T18:14:23.738300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=667M(130.4%)
2019-01-10T18:14:23.738300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2019-01-10T18:14:37.657497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-01-10T18:14:37.657497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-01-10T18:14:37.814331+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-01-10T18:14:55.792511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=extremeparts.herokuapp.com request_id=0fadedcd-d387-493a-bd0a-1b6463eb5ae1 fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-10T18:15:02.902463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=extremeparts.happyfeed.io request_id=6a9c86ee-1ae9-427f-bd2b-b088d04e6050 fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-01-10T18:21:57.484369+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=extremeparts.happyfeed.io request_id=0bb304e5-744c-40fd-949d-516d15f9f244 fwd="66.207.216.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Comment: could be out of memory. Try to increase available memory

Comment: @Aldarund I was thinking the same thing, but this is just a nuxt app.. nothing very big in terms of size. I am paying for the $7/dyno atm, kind of silly if it can't run this off the non-free version still

Comment: 512 mb of dyno should be enough for run. But you are also building it there, and for build it might be not enough. I suggest not to build it on dynos, just run on it

Comment: @Aldarund Thanks for the response! Yeah you might be right. Strange considering I have about 5 other dyno's with a similar build of this app all running. 
The build is also succeeding with this dyno but I am asked to view the heroku logs after I hit the URL.. I've upgraded this one dyno to the $25 tier, I am redeploying now just to be safe and will report back if it's giving the same errors!

Comment: Typical production build nuxt app use 100-200mb of memory.

Comment: @Aldarund Okay.. it's up and running. This is a head scratcher to me since I have so many running on the other $7 paid dyno's and they seem to be performing alright. Would it be bad if now that it is running I downgrade from the $25/m back to the $7/m? I can't believe how expensive heroku is, I should have just hosted these statically through aws and a lambda function for serverless. Btw, if its 100-200mb of memory, shouldn't the 512mb enough? Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Aldarund Okay.. must not be the memory. I just did another change and deploy and this time it's crashed/is staying down. Wth Heroku!

Comment: Yes, 512 should be enough

Comment: It would most likely be an issue loading dependencies, try re-deploying using lesser dependencies as a test and then make an informed decision as to what dependencies can be avoided in your requirements.txt file